# On Ubuntu installed NginX and Can't find where new WWW root is

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

On Ubuntu 13.04 the original WWW was in /var/www/ then I installed NginX and it installed correctly but I can't find the actual folder accessible by http (I looked in /etc/nginx/). I searched for index.htm, index.html and index.php but there are hundreds of results.

Is there a command I can run to tell me what folder http is pointed to? I tried searching for this but I am not sure what keywords to use .

Places I looked in:

```
/usr/share/nginx/www
/usr/share/www
/usr/share/html
/var/www
/etc/nginx/
```

Comment: Check the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. Find `root` line in the first `server` section. It defines default web root folder and you can change it, if you like. There can be more `server` sections defined, as well, with different root folders (that's how you create virtual hosts).

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu if you installed with apt-get it is /usr/share/ngnix/www

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
dpkg -L nginx
```

you should see where it put any files.